# JHipster and AngularJS: How to deal with the CSRF in AJAX requests properly?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, csrf, jhipster

I have to create another simple html page for the JHipster, and it has to execute AJAX requests. It contains a tiny AngularJS app, so I copied some of the JHipster code:

`var app = angular.module('app', ['dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3']);
    app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'CSRF-TOKEN';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRF-TOKEN';
    });`

Then I execute HTTP requests like this:

`$http.post("/controller/execute", {code: ourCode})`

And that generates an error. However, then I reload the page and everything works like a charm. Then I grep'ed the sources and found that in auth.session.service.js you use following code to obtain a CSRF token:
`$http.get('api/account');`

I added this snippet to my webapp and it works great now.

However I wonder if there's a better solution (avoiding the extra request?).
I suspect the question is too broad, but can't think how to make it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, JHipster handles CSRF properly, using Spring Security on the server-side and AngularJS on the client-side.

As you said you just copied some code from JHipster: are you really using JHipster, or just copy/pasting the client-side code? This won't work if you don't have a server correctly configured, that's where our work is.

Normally you shouldn't have to copy/paste that AngularJS configuration, we do all that for you.